# Avoid copying all constructors in subclasses

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor

So a base class has multiple constructors:

```
sf::Sprite()
sf::Sprite(const Texture& texture)
sf::Sprite(const Texture& texture, const IntRect& rectangle)
```

And I'm subclassing this class multiple times:

```
class Sub : public sf::Sprite {
    public:
        Sub() : sf::Sprite() {};
        Sub(const Texture& texture) : sf::Sprite(texture) {};
        Sub(const Texture& texture, const IntRect& rectangle) : sf::Sprite(texture, rectangle) {};

        // My subclass specific code
};
```

As you see, I have to repeat these three constructors for every subclass. Is there a way to avoid this, since the constructors usually don't do anything special? *Sometimes* I need *some* class specific initialization though, so it's not always viable to just straight out copy everything.

Comment: `using` should do it for you: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration

Comment: What precisely do you mean by *some class specific initialization*? Please provide an example in your post.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can accomplish this by [inheriting constructors](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration#Inheriting_constructors) (since C++11).

> If the using-declaration refers to a constructor of a direct base of the class being defined (e.g. `using Base::Base;`), all constructors of that base (ignoring member access) are made visible to overload resolution when initializing the derived class.

e.g.

```
class Sub : public sf::Sprite {
    public:
        using sf::Sprite::Sprite;

        // My subclass specific code
};
```

If the inherited constructors is used to initialize a `Sub`, the `sf::Sprite` subobject is initialized using the inherited constructor, and all other members of `Sub` are initialized as if by the defaulted default constructor.

If there're some special cases need to be processed, you still can define constructor(s) in `Sub`, the inherited constructor with the same signature will be hidden.

> As with using-declarations for any other non-static member functions, if an inherited constructor matches the signature of one of the constructors of Derived, it is hidden from lookup by the version found in Derived.

Comment: Wouldn't this not work due to this though: *"Sometimes I need some class specific initialization though, so it's not always viable to just straight out copy everything."*

Comment: Note that this won't add the default constructor to ``Sub``.

Comment: @MarkusMeskanen Answer revised. If I understand correctly, you can still provide constructors in `Sub` if necessary.

Comment: Wow, how had I not realised this until now? I'm sure I've heard of these in passing and didn't register that I can make use of them. /sweeps codebase

Comment: Wait, so you need to still declare the copy and move constructors? Otherwise, if the quote is taken literal "[…]and all other members of Sub are initialized as if by the defaulted default constructor.", a using-based copy-constructor would default-initialise the other members instead of doing what a defaulted copy-constructor would do?

Comment: Can we follow same pattern for php ?

Comment: @JonasWielicki No. The inheriting constructors won't prevent the generation of implicit declared copy/move constructor for the derived class.

Answer (score 15):

You can use the `using` keyword to inherit the constructor of your base class, excluding the special ones (default, copy, move). To shorten your default constructor simply use  `= default`. If you want class specific initialization you can simply write the constructor again, just as you do now.

```
class Sub : public sf::Sprite {
    public:
        Sub() = default;
        using sf::Sprite::Sprite;

        Sub(const Texture& texture) 
        {
           // your custom code.
        };

        // My subclass specific code
};
```

Answer (score 7):

If you can just 'inherit' the constructor, i.e. have one with exactly the same arguments, simply use `using` as explained in the other answers. However, if your `derived` class's constructor has additional arguments and/or requires **some class specific initialization**, you may use a variadic template.

```
struct base
{
  base(int);
  base(std::string const&);
  base(some_type const&);
  base(std::string const&, some_type const&);
  /* ... */
};

struct derived : base
{
  template<typename...Args>
  derived(some_other_type const&x, Args&&...args)
  : base(std::forward<Args>(args)...)
  , private_datum(x)
  {
    construction_details();          // class-specific initialisation
  }
private:
  some_other_type private_datum;
  void construction_details();       // implemented in source code
};
```

Comment: True, but this potentially means having to expose implementation details in the class definition/header, so I think in many cases, all the extra typing of manually forwarding the specific arguments etc is far preferable.

Comment: How is adding another argument for derived class use and forwarding the rest “exposing”?  If anything it exposes less, since you don’t have to repeat the declarations from the base, and it automatically follows if you change the base.

Comment: @underscore_d I don't get it. Perhaps you can explain? How is the alternative of several (four in my example) near-identical constructors less exposing? If you're worried about the constructor body, then you can simply replace that with a call to some private member (see edit).

Comment: Right, good points. I probably haven't thought about this pattern enough. :)